# What is the most robust way to establish SSH (and VNC) connection to my Linux Machine when I'm away?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I have two computers, a MacBook Pro running Big Sur and a desktop running Ubuntu 20.04. I live in a building which provides its own wired Internet connection. I have a local WiFi setup which connects to the MacBook Pro and the Linux machine. I have routinely used ssh on the local network without problems.

However, in about a week, I have to move away and leave the desktop behind. I need access to my Linux machine via the Internet. I have tried to test if remote access works by connecting my MacBook Pro to the Internet via my phone. While the computer is able to browse the web, I am not able to access the Linux machine via ssh.

How can I accomplish this? I think my router is behind a NAT as the router's reported IP address is different than the one I find from `https://www.whatismyip.com/`.

For SSH, I have opened the WAN port of 60000 and the LAN port of 22 forwards to my Linux machine. Some things to note: wherever I move, I won't have admin access to the network. I can connect to it but I am not sure what is blocked on that network. The IP address of the MacBook Pro may also change.

What is the most robust way to establish SSH (and VNC) connection to my Linux Machine when I'm away?

Answer (score 1):

The most robust way to do this is a fair step harder - set up a VPN (eg OpenVPN, ideally on your router, although you can use another box and port forward to that).  Then SSH in across the VPN connection.   By using (for example a standard UDP based OpenVPN) tunnel, you are getting an IP address in your network which is not tied to whatever connection you are connecting from, and you have an additional layer of encryption.  It will also allow you to use VNC.

I suspect the answer you are looking for though, is to either open port 22 on the WAN port, or specify port 6000 from your remote computer (rather then use the default on port 22).  On command line based clients this is done with something like

```
 ssh -p 60000 ip.addr.of.server
```

While its not easy to use vnc over SSH, you can still do "X Forwarding" which will allow you to run graphical applications on the remote computer and display a terminal on your local computer.  To do this you will need to enable X Forwarding on SSH, and you wil likely also want to enable compression

```
 ssh -p 60000 -CX ip.addr.of.server
```

Comment: I would prefer the harder way as long as its more robust. I can purchase a VPS or setup a custom firmware on my router. What is the preferred method?

Comment: If you have a static IP address I would set up OpenVPN on my router.  (I use - and recommend DD-WRT if your router supports it).  This will allow you to access any devices you need to behind your router, rather then just one.  Its also easier to work with as it means 1 openvpn client rather then 2.

Comment: Looks like my router isn't supported by DD-WRT.

Comment: My guess is its not an ethernet only router then.  What make and model and firmware options do you have?

Comment: NetGear 6120. Firmware is V1.0.0.72. Open-WRT seems to be supported.

Comment: OpenWRT can work.  Its been a long time (10+years) since I last did it - it had a relatively steep learning curve because it didn't have a GUI.  Not sure if thats changed.

Comment: Hang on - just saw this - "How can I accomplish this? I think my router is behind a NAT as the router's reported IP address is different than the one I find from https://www.whatismyip.com/."  - If you can't connect to your routers external IP address, a VPN running on the router wont help you - you will need to go the VPS route :<

Comment: Ah okay, good thing the flashing didn't work. I'll go purchase a VPS.